# pull only the last commit from remote and put it on the top

Tags: git

I've got commits on two remotes

```
origin 1-2-3-4-5-A
upstream 1-2-3-4-5-6-7
```

On my local machine I've got the upstream version of commits.

But the question is how to acquire the commit A from origin and put it on the top of my current commits? I mean the result should be `1-2-3-4-5-6-7-A`.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork

Comment: You cannot get `1-2-3-4-5-6-7-A`. You *can* get `1-2-3-4-5-6-7-A'` though by merging.

Comment: Yes I understand it won't be `A` but `A'`(but `A` only basically adds files and does not change other files so I reference it as `A`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's exactly what [`git cherry-pick`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) is for.

Switch your local repo to the branch that you want to change. Then:

```
git cherry-pick A
```

You can specify the commit with its SHA hash, or you can just use the branch name to pick the last commit.

Comment: It's possible you have to do a `git fetch` before cherry-picking to get the commit you desire on your locale machine.